# How to read a table into R from a PHP website

Tags: r, web, url

I'm looking at an R script that I found online related to fantasy football predictions, and the code is a little outdated so I'm trying to make it work for this season of the NFL. I am somewhat familiar with R but I don't know anything about HTML or PHP, and in order to gather the player's data I need the table from this URL: http://www.fantasypros.com/nfl/rankings/consensus-cheatsheets.php

This is the line of code that they used to extract the table, but it doesn't seem to work anymore.

`experts <- data.table(readHTMLTable("http://www.fantasypros.com/nfl/rankings/consensus-cheatsheets.php", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)$data)`

It simple says
`Error: failed to load external entity "http://www.fantasypros.com/nfl/rankings/consensus-cheatsheets.php"`

I've looked up different ways to pull tables out of a website, but they are all unique to that particular table. Any way I could get all of this data into a data frame in R?

Comment: Please only add tags that are relevant to the actual issue. This question has nothing to do with PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had the same problem and the easiest workaround I found for this issue is downloading the file before loading it into R.
Since you want to turn the HTML file into a table, the best solution is using `readHTMLTable()`, then you'll load a list of data frames.
Here follows the code to solve it:

```
library(XML)

file_url = 'http://www.fantasypros.com/nfl/rankings/consensus-cheatsheets.php'
file_path = '~/Desktop/nfl.html'
download.file(file_url, file_path)
doc = readHTMLTable(file_path)
```

Here is the output:
[image]

Let us know if it worked for you too.

Comment: Well, it downloaded the HTML file alright, but I still can't extract the data table from the file. Thank you for the help though! Do you know of any way to turn this code I've downloaded into a usable table?

Comment: hey @NathanKilcrease, i updated the code.. i think now you have what you want!